# Can I control the page where a mobile user lands when logged into CommCareHQ?

Tags: commcare

I currently have a mobile worker who has access to Web Apps, but also to reports (based on the web "Role" of the user), and by default, when I log into my project space as this mobile worker, the landing page is the Web Apps page, with the option to navigate to Reports. I'd however, like to have the mobile worker land on the Reports page, with the option to navigate to Web Apps. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

On the Web Users & Roles page of your domain, if you find the "Roles" table, locate the role in question, and click on Edit for the role, you'll see a popup window. In that window, there will be a dropdown option for "Default Landing Page", which you can then configure.